# How to understand the 3 lines of c code?

Tags: php, c, syntax, php-internals

```
 if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "|l", &flag) == FAILURE) {
  return;
 }
```

Especially what's `ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC` doing?

Comment: the short answer would be...read the documentation; see http://www.google.com/search?q=ZEND_NUM_ARGS%28%29

Comment: @Steven: Actually, that is C code for the PHP language.

Comment: That looks like C code for a PHP extension.

Comment: @Bolt I stand (sit, actually) corrected; which 10 seconds with the documentation available from google told me right after i clicked the add comment button [you guys are fast!]

Comment: i expect this will be closed soon, since the OP has apparently expended no effort prior to posting, but i'll leave it alone...for now

Answer (score 5):

It looks like TSRMLS_CC is a macro that might expand to nothing or it might expand to an extra argument with a comma thrown in there:

http://blog.golemon.com/2006/06/what-heck-is-tsrmlscc-anyway.html

Answer (score 4):

This [Zend article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1022) says:

> The bulk of the
>   zend_parse_parameters() block will
>   almost always look the same.
>   ZEND_NUM_ARGS() **provides a hint to the
>   Zend Engine** about the parameters which
>   are to be retrieved, TSRMLS_CC is
>   present to ensure thread safety

Comment: Can you elaborate about `TSRMLS_CC` ?

Answer (score 1):

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_07.htm

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.hospedajeydominios.com/mambo/documentacion-manual_php-pagina-zend_arguments_retrieval.html